# Обращение к элементам коллекции

Tags: c#, коллекции

Есть 5 объектов:

```
Credit1 obj1;
Credit2 obj2;
Credit3 obj3;
Credit4 obj4;
Credit5 obj5;
```

Все наследуются от одного класса с определённым интерфейсом. То есть - одинаковые классы. Зачем? Вот и я не знаю, но эти классы есть, и нужно реализовать поиск и сортировку по этим объектам. Ладно бы поиск, его можно сделать через костыли, но как сортировать то, что не объединено ни в одну структуру?..

Решено было объединить всё в одну коллекцию:

```
var list = new List<MainCredit>();
list.Add(new Credit1());
list.Add(new Credit2());
list.Add(new Credit3());
list.Add(new Credit4());
list.Add(new Credit5());
```

Возникает вопрос, как обратиться к методам этих объектов?

```
foreach (MainCredit obj in list)
{
     obj.prtInfo(); // Будет обращение к методу prtInfo() у MainCredit, а надо Credit1-5
}
```

Пробовал ещё этот вариант:

```
foreach (MainCredit obj in list)
{
    if (obj is Credit1)
        (obj as Credit1).prtInfo();
}
```

[image: Результат]
Базовый класс:

```
public interface InterfaceMainCredit
{
    int InterestRate();
    void prtInfo();
    void prtFile(StreamWriter writer, BinaryWriter writer2nd, MainCredit obj);
    void binaryPrtFile(BinaryWriter writer, MainCredit obj);
    void binaryLoadFromFile(BinaryReader reader);
}

public class MainCredit : InterfaceMainCredit
{
    protected string currency, time, method;

    public virtual void prtInfo() { ... }
    public int InterestRate() { ... }
    public void prtFile(StreamWriter writer, BinaryWriter writer2nd, MainCredit obj){ ... }
    public void binaryPrtFile(BinaryWriter writer, MainCredit obj) { ... }
    public void binaryLoadFromFile(BinaryReader reader) { ... }
}
```

Дочерние классы:

```
class Credit1 : MainCredit
{
    int interestRate, provisionForLoan, number, amountOfCredit;
    string name;

    public override void prtInfo() { ... }
    ...
}
```

Comment: а как же virtual, abstract и overfloat ???

Comment: приведите объявление _MainCredit_ и классов наследников

Comment: если метод prtInfo класса MainCredit абстрактный или виртуальный, а классы Credit1...Credit5 его переопределяют, то у каждого из наследников будет вызываться своя версия этого метода, а не метод из MainCredit. Если же метод не виртуальный, однако все наследники имеют перекрытые методы с такой же сигнатурой и названием, то имеет смысл это изменить

Comment: А это вопрос не к нам, а к архитектору проекта. Его и спросите, как он собрался решать эти проблемы. По поводу вызова методов, методы, определённые в базовом классе, можно вызывать без проблем.

Comment: @VladD, в данном случае - только публичные методы определенные в базовом классе

Comment: приводить к базовому классу (судя из описания он есть) по нему и делать поиск и сортировку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Юзайте virtual и override, если это Ваши классы

```
public class MainCredit 
{
  public virtual void prtInfo()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Say-0");
  }
}

public class Credit1 : MainCredit
{
  public override void prtInfo()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Say-1");
  }
}

public class Credit2 : MainCredit
{
  public override void prtInfo()
  {
    base.prtInfo();
    Console.WriteLine("Say-2");
  }
}

void test()
{
  MainCredit A = new Credit1();
  A.prtInfo(); //в консоль напишет Say-1

  MainCredit B = new Credit2();
  B.prtInfo(); //в консоль напишет "Say-0 \n Say-2"
}
```

Comment: В базовом классе:
`public virtual void prtInfo() {...}`
В остальных:
`public override void prtInfo() {...}`

Ситуация как на скрине, вывод с пустыми полями.

Comment: @АлексейЯгело, на скрине Вы добавляете в коллекцию созданные пустые объекты, откуда там данные? Добавьте туда реальные данные, тот же obj1 и перепроверьте.

Answer (score 1):

Если у Вас не доступа к исходным классам, для того что бы нормально их переписать с использованием override или наследования от virtual/abstract, то можно воспользоваться рефлексией.

```
foreach (MainCredit obj in list)
{
    var result = obj.GetType().GetMethod("pInfo").Invoke(obj, null);
}
```